# React Native: Issue with Navigation - Unable to Navigate Between Screens

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm currently facing a problem with navigation in my React Native project. I am using React Navigation, and when I try to navigate from one screen to another, nothing happens. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```js
// App.js
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import DetailsScreen from './screens/DetailsScreen';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

```js
// HomeScreen.js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

export default function HomeScreen() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const handleNavigate = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Details');
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Welcome to the Home Screen!</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleNavigate}>
        <Text>Go to Details Screen</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Despite setting up the navigation stack and using the navigate function, nothing happens when I press the "Go to Details Screen" text. There are no errors in the console, and I'm unsure where the issue might be. Can someone please provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this problem? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!